# Altering markup of language switcher

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

I want to lightly alter the language switcher block's markup by adding additional classes, among others "clearfix" to clear the floats. I cannot however pin down where the markup is created.

This link http://drupal.org/node/1369090 (last post) suggests using template.php but again, I cannot see how I would alter the wrapper div's markup.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In D7, the language switcher block is created in `locale_block_view()`:

```
function locale_block_view($type) {
  if (drupal_multilingual()) {
    $path = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
    $links = language_negotiation_get_switch_links($type, $path);

    if (isset($links->links)) {
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'locale') . '/locale.css');
      $class = "language-switcher-{$links->provider}";
      $variables = array('links' => $links->links, 'attributes' => array('class' => array($class)));
      $block['content'] = theme('links__locale_block', $variables);
      $block['subject'] = t('Languages');
      return $block;
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `hook_block_view_alter()` to modify the markup of the block.

If you want modify the output of the links, you can override the `theme_links()` function in your theme using `THEME_links__locale_block()` in the template.php file.

Comment: Could you expand on the "you can use hook_block_view_alter" part?  I've tried implementing this a few ways and its now working.